# Removing date from an entire column of date&time data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time, dataset

I am working with large data sets from a water quality sensor that relays the date and time in the format: **25-Jun-2018 15:16:51**

I would like to remove the date portion from the entire column of Date/Time data, however I am finding it hard to do so because I am extremely new to python.

I was able to remove the date from a single piece of data using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['25-Jun-2018 15:17:49']})
df

                 time
0   25-Jun-2018 15:17:49

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time
df

      time
0   15:17:49
```

Can anybody help me do this to an entire column of data at once? The data looks like this.

```
water_level_time = pd.DataFrame()
water_level_time = df[['Date / Time']]
water_level_time

        Date / Time
0   25-Jun-2018 15:16:51
1   25-Jun-2018 15:16:53
2   25-Jun-2018 15:16:55
3   25-Jun-2018 15:16:57
4   25-Jun-2018 15:16:59
5   25-Jun-2018 15:17:1
6   25-Jun-2018 15:17:3
7   25-Jun-2018 15:17:5
8   25-Jun-2018 15:17:7
9   25-Jun-2018 15:17:9
```

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow and didn't know how to format the In and Out cells

Comment: What about the approach in the first cell, `pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.time`, isn't working for the entire column?

Comment: It may work, however I'm not sure how to reference the entire column in this context.

Comment: In exactly the same way. `df['Date / Time']` returns a `panas.Series` which you can then operate on with `.dt.time` without issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas then use lambda function.

```
df['date_val'] = df['Date / Time'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.date)

df['time_val'] = df['Date / Time'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.time)
```